# Change state using "onClick"/"onSubmit" according to button click

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to identify a `Student` or a `Counselor` based on the button that is clicked.

What I am trying to achieve is that, if the user clicks on the `Counselor` button, `isCounselor` will become `true`, if the other button is clicked, then `isStudent` will become `true`.

I have tried both `onClick` and `onSubmit` but the state remains the same.

Therefore, I believe I have done something wrong but not sure where. I have just started using `react-redux` and cannot get my head around it!

The reducer is included in the `combineReducers` and I have created the types in the code below:

**reducer**

```js
import { IS_COUNSELOR, IS_STUDENT } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  isCounselor: false,
  isStudent: false,
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case IS_COUNSELOR:
      return {
        ...state,
        isCounselor: true,
        isStudent: false,
      };
    case IS_STUDENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        isCounselor: false,
        isStudent: true,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**action**

```js
import { IS_COUNSELOR, IS_STUDENT } from "./types";

// IS COUNSELOR
export const toCounselor = () => {
  return {
    type: IS_COUNSELOR,
    payload: { isCounselor, isStudent },
  };
};

// IS STUDENT
export const toStudent = () => {
  return {
    type: IS_STUDENT,
    payload: { isCounselor, isStudent },
  };
};
```

**component**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { toCounselor, toStudent } from "../../actions/clients";

export class Welcome extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    isCounselor: PropTypes.bool,
    isStudent: PropTypes.bool,
    toCounselor: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    toStudent: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  onSubmitCounselor = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.toCounselor();
  };

  onSubmitStudent = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.toStudent();
  };

  render() {
    return (
            {/* some divs */}
                <div className="col-md-6 mt-3">
                  <Link to="/register" className="nav-link">
                    <button
                      type="submit"
                      className="btn btn-success"
                      // name="isStudent"
                      onSubmit={this.onSubmitStudent}
                    >
                      I am a Student
                    </button>
                  </Link>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-6 mt-3">
                  <Link to="/register" className="nav-link">
                    <button
                      type="submit"
                      className="btn btn-info"
                      // name="isCounselor"
                      onSubmit={this.onSubmitCounselor}
                    >
                      I am a Counselor
                    </button>
                  </Link>
                </div>
            {/* some other divs */}
    );
  }
}

export default Welcome;
```

Could you please advise? Thank you!

Comment: You should pass the function to the `onClick` prop in the `Link` component instead and connect the component to the redux store

Comment: @LadiAdenusi Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, when I do that I get the error ```Uncaught ReferenceError: isCounselor is not defined```

Comment: I have posted an answer that should help

Answer (score 2):

Your Welcome component does not seem to be connected to the redux state, thus it is not receiving data from the store and the actions are not dispatched in the redux loop.

The following code is not ready as is but should give you a working path

```js
// Connect the Redux Store (state) to the component props
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isCounselor: state.isCounselor,
  isStudent: state.isStudent,
});

// Updated thanks to the comment of Drew Reese below
const mapDispatchToProps = { toCounselor, toStudent };

// Previous version
// const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({ toCounselor, toStudent }, dispatch);

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Welcome)
```

You should have a look at this [section of the documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) and [here about the bindActionCreators](https://redux.js.org/api/bindactioncreators)

Comment: BTW, the `connect` HOC's `mapDispatchToProps` automatically decorates action creators with a call to `bind`, so you can simply `mapDispatchToProps = { toCounselor, toStudent };`

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! It was super helpful! I imported ```{ connect }``` from ```react-redux``` and did what suggested. However, it is still not working. I have also tried to use ```isCounselr: state.users.isCounselor``` etc. but it still does not work. Is there something wrong in **actions** or in my use of ```onSubmit```?

Comment: @GRipepi if you add some logging, can you see if the actions are called? If the function in the reducer is called?

Comment: @AdlenAfane It is not, it just calls ```@@INIT```.

Comment: @AdlenAfane Sorry didn't get it...when I do the logging, the functions are not called. Seems like my ```onSubmit``` is not calling the any func and if I change to ```onClick``` I get this error: ```Uncaught ReferenceError: isCounselor is not defined```

Comment: @GRipepi Have you checked that your reducers are added to the redux middleware when you create the store? Can you update your question with where/how you wrap your app and setup your store?

Comment: @AdlenAfane That is set up correctly as I have other reducers which work.

Comment: @GRipepi if it is in the component, you may need to access it from the props `this.props. isCounselor`

Comment: You also may need to define a constructor to bind the `onSubmitCounselor`.
Something like:
```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.onSubmitCounselor = this.onSubmitCounselor.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: @AdlenAfane Is there a way I can work out wether the action is working or not?

Comment: @AdlenAfane I made it call the ```action``` by changing the action ```toCounselor = () => {...}``` to ```toCounselor = (isCounselor, isStudent) => {...}```  and passing ```this.props.isCounselor, ...``` in the component. I also removed  ```onSubmit``` from the button and added ```onClick``` to the ```Link```. However, ```Link``` is now broken and does not open ```.../register```. LOL

Comment: @AdlenAfane All sorted! Just wanted to thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In your action file, do this...

```
import { IS_COUNSELOR, IS_STUDENT } from "./types";

// IS COUNSELOR
export const toCounselor = () => ({ type: IS_COUNSELOR });

// IS STUDENT
export const toStudent = () => ({ type: IS_STUDENT });
```

Inside the render, pass the function to the `onClick` prop of the `Link` component

Then at the end of your component, do this...

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isCounselor: state.isCounselor,
  isStudent: state. isStudent,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = { toCounselor, toStudent };

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Welcome)
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I guess that the issue is caused by ```onSubmit```.